# tkinter not letting 2 threads run at once

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x, tkinter-canvas

I have a game and I have the world moving towards you, and you can jump at the same time. both functions work separately, but they don't work when used together. sometimes it gives me an error(ValueError: could not convert string to float: expected) couldnt convert, sometimes the character does a weird jittery motion, sometimes it does both, and sometimes it just crashes. this is my code

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
import thread
from time import sleep


def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        retVal = True
    else:
        retVal = False
    return retVal


class gameScreen:

    def move(self, event):
        d = self.getdir(event.keysym)
        self.canvas.move(self.char, d[0], d[1])
        self.canvas.update()
        if self.collision():
            self.canvas.move(self.char, -d[0], -d[1])

    def fall(self):
        speed = .01
        x = 0
        while not self.collision():
            self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, 1)
            self.canvas.update()
            sleep(speed)
            if x == 2:
                speed -= speed *.04
                x = 0
            else:
                x += 1
        self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, -1)

    def jump(self):
        j = 0
        from time import sleep
        jump = [6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0]

        for i in range(0, (len(jump)*2)):
            x = jump[j]
            self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, -x)
            if not  is_even(i):
                j +=1
            self.canvas.update()
            sleep(.05)
        self.fall()

    def getLast(self, lvl):
        x = 0
        for i in lvl:
            coords = self.canvas.coords(i)
            if x < coords[3]:
                x = coords[3]
                last = i
        return last

    def gameThread(self, event):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.gameStart, ())

    def gameStart(self, event=None):
        from time import sleep
        last = self.getLast(self.lvl1)
        coords = self.canvas.coords(last)

        while coords[2] > 0:
            print coords[2]
            for i in self.lvl1:
                self.canvas.move(i, -1, 0)
            coords = self.canvas.coords(last)
            self.canvas.update()
            sleep(.002)
            if not self.touchingGround(event):
                self.fall()

    def touchingGround(self, event = None):
        self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, 5)

        if self.collision():

            retVal = True
        else:
            retVal = False
        self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, -5)
        return retVal

    def onKey(self, event):
        if self.touchingGround(event):
            thread.start_new_thread(self.jump, ())

    def collision(self):
        coords = self.canvas.coords(self.char)
        collision =  len(self.canvas.find_overlapping(coords[0]-1, 
                                                      coords[1]-1,
                                                      coords[2]-1, 
                                                      coords[3]-1)) >=2
        return collision

    def getdir(self, s):
        direction = {"Left":[-5, 0], "Right":[5, 0]}
        try:
            retVal = direction[s]
        except KeyError:
            retVal =False
        return retVal

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.lvl1 = []
        self.objects = []
        self.master = master
        master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        master.title("Game")
        self.width=master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height=master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width=self.width,
                                      height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack(expand="YES",fill="both")
        self.objects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, self.height,
                                                         self.width,
                                                         self.height-100,
                                                         fill="grey"))
        self.lvl1.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.width,
                                                         self.height-100,
                                                         self.width + 100,
                                                         self.height-150,
                                                         fill="grey"))
        self.objects.extend(self.lvl1)
        self.char = self.canvas.create_rectangle((self.width/2)-25, 
                                                 self.height- 100,
                                                 (self.width/2)+25, 
                                                 self.height-150, 
                                                 fill="red")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        master.bind("<Key-Up>", self.onKey)
        master.bind("<Return>", self.onKey)


def destroy(event):
    root.destroy()


root = tkinter.Tk()
my_gui = gameScreen(root)
root.bind("<Escape>", destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

i tried adding the afters like tadhg said, but it still only jumps sometimes, and most of the time it dosent do a full jump, or just goes up one or two pixels, then goes back down, then repeats for the amount of time it should be jumping.

Comment: `tkinter`, `threads` and `time.sleep` all do not get along.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: when I use after, they don't happen simultaneously, I need them happening at the same time

Comment: then the function you are passing to `after` needs to only move it once then call `after` on a function that will move it a little more etc.

Comment: they happen simultaniosly, but the box just jumps a little, then falls back down, not doing a full jump, and if it does do a full jump, it isnt simultanious